# How to compile to bin folder on Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a src directory containing other directories and class files. However when I change a class in the src directory the relative class file is not updated in the bin folder. Why does Intellij not automatically compile but Eclipse for example does?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your project settings to "Make Project automatically".

To do this, go to Preferences, Compiler and click the checkbox.

(Intellij IDEA 13.1 Ultimate)

Comment: It seems to work fine for me. It doesn't always happen immediately, it might be that there is a delay before your autosave kicks in. From the IntelliJ IDEA Help : "Select this check box to automatically make (compile) the project on every save or autosave."