# How to update .class file in Intellij in bin directory?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've imported a project into Intellij and modify some lines of code in my java file. However, after `Build Project`, the `.class` file in `bin` directory still keeps the same and does not have any change. I read this question  [How to compile to bin folder on Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837466/how-to-compile-to-bin-folder-on-intellij) and changed my settings to `Make project automatically`. It still does not work. Can anybody tell me how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

If it is compiled properly, the `.class` files should change unless there is any compilation error. I don't know about `Intellij` but `.class` should change in any case. please check the `.class` files are built in another folder or not?

Comment: The `bin` and `src` are under the same directory of the project.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA copies your module's compiled source classes to the [module's compiler output directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/specifying-compilation-settings.html#compilation_output_folders). Check the corresponding compiled class in that directory. Also check other [compiler settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/specifying-compilation-settings.html#configure_compiler_settings) like [*Excludes*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/excludes.html) and make sure the file/folder is not added for the compiler to ignore it.